# img maximized in the background inside a div

Tags: css

I have been fiddling around with this for some time now, but I still don't understand how it should be done.

I would like the image to be maximized (100%/100%) in the background of the itemtemplate div, but right now it just makes it fit inside the div which is 250px/250px.

```
<div class="itemtemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <img style="-ms-grid-row-span: 2;" src="#" data-win-bind="src: backgroundImage; alt: title" />
    <div class="item-overlay">
        <h4 class="item-title" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h4>
        <h6 class="item-subtitle win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: subtitle">
        </h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas ? thx.

Answer (score 2):

You can position the image absolutely and set the height and width to 100% in your CSS files.

```
.itemtemplate > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
}
```

Just make sure you remember to position the parent div and the other children of .itemtemplate relatively:

```
.itemtemplate, .itemtemplate > div {
    position: relative;
}
```

The parent needs to be positioned relatively to ensure the `img` is positioned within that element. The other children of the parent need to positioned relatively to ensure that they are drawn above img (as positioned elements are drawn after static elements). If you have trouble seeing the other child elements then you can set their z-index.

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sjsNJ/**

Comment: Beat me to it :) Here's another working example for you in case you are having z-index issues: http://jsfiddle.net/yeQkv/

Answer (score 0):

Need to use CSS background-image.

```
div.itemtemplate
{
    background:url(PATH_TO_IMAGE);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

See site below for more info.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: It is very important to note that this is only supportive in modern browsers. Here is a better reference for css background-size: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size

Comment: @CalebKester what browsers do you class as modern?

Comment: Modern browsers is the term used for the latest versions of browsers that support HTML5 and CSS3.  To see specifically which browsers support background-size: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size#section_6

Comment: @westo if that was a serious question http://bethesignal.org/blog/2011/02/19/modern-browsers-ship/ if it was /sarcasm then check http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t45 as IE would fail! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the attributes you are using. But, in order to use an image for the background. There are couple of ways.

1. If it is `<body>` or `<table>` you can also define them by using doing something like this

   ```
   <body background="link/to/image.jpg">
   ```
2. But the global way, which every element supports would be to define them using CSS

   ```
   <div style="background-image: url("link/to/image")">...</div>
   ```

*Now, coming to the image part*

Whenever you are using a background image,

- It is never going to re-size to fit the container. Unless you use CSS3.

  ```
  /* CSS3 Snippet to resize a background */
  div
  {
      background-image:url("link/to/image");
      -moz-background-size:80px 60px;
      background-size:80px 60px;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
  }
  ```
- If the container is big, it will start repeating itself to fill the area. Which can be controlled to repeat or not repeat. Like

  ```
  div { 
      background-image: url("link/to/image");
      background-repeat: no-repeat; /* similary repeat-x and repeat-y */
  }
  ```

---

However, what you are trying to use in using a `<img />` to **act** as a background, which is semantically wrong and I do not recommend it.